# free( ) pointers

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I'm required to use a special library to keep track of my memory leaks where `malloc()= allocate( )` and `free( ) = unallocate( )`.

I'm trying to complete free a `linked-list` but it seems like the "root" value isn't being freed.

```
typedef struct _node {
    struct _node *child;
    char *command;
} Command_list;

void delete_commands(Command_list **root)
{
    Command_list *temp;
    while( *root != NULL ){
        temp = (*root)->child;
        //printf("STRING: %s\n", *root->command );
        unallocate( *root );
        *root = temp;

    }
}
```

The function that's calling it

```
void file_processing( .... ){
    Command_list *root = allocate(sizeof (Command_list));
    root = NULL;
....
        delete_commands( &root );  
    }
}
```

I believe that

```
Command_list *root = allocate(sizeof (Command_list))
```

isn't being properly de-allocated for some reason. 
Anyone can give me some hints?

**UPDATE:**  I found out that instead of

```
Command_list *root = allocate(sizeof (Command_list));
        root = NULL;
```

this works:

```
Command_list *root = NULL;
```

Can someone explain to me why would the first method not work? Thanks! :)

Comment: There's probably an error in the `....` part you though you can leave out.

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't anything wrong with the code in between as a different attempt seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: I don't follow. Why were you setting `root = NULL` just after allocating memory in the first place?

Comment: urm, I wasn't actually sure what would allocate do. Just wanted to make sure that the root is NULL at that point.

Comment: Well, whatever it does, you're losing its results by saying `root=NULL` just afterward, and you're probably leaking memory.

Comment: what library is this? have you looked up its documentation for how it's done? There is nothing one can reply to this without this information, except speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
void delete_commands(Command_list *root) // Pass the pointer, not the pointer's address
{
    Command_list *temp;
    while(root != NULL)
    {
        temp = root->child;
        //printf("STRING: %s\n", *root->command );
        unallocate(root);
        root = temp;
    }
}

void file_processing( .... ){
    Command_list *root = allocate(sizeof (Command_list));
    root = NULL; // ERROR : you lost the pointer, you probably mean to null the command and child node
    root->command = NULL;
    root->child = NULL;
....
        delete_commands(root); // Pass the pointer, not the pointer's address
        root = NULL; // Now everything is freed, you can nullify this pointer
    }
}
```

**About the update :**
The second version works because you don't allocate anything, so thr is nothing to free.

Answer (score 0):

```
Command_list *root = allocate(sizeof (Command_list));
    root = NULL;
```

Here you are loosing one element of root.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
void file_processing( .... ){
    Command_list *root = allocate(sizeof (Command_list));
    root = NULL;
    ...
    delete_commands( &root );
```

Are you making root=NULL first and then invoking delete_commands ?

2) delete_commands () does not deallocate root node [first node], but it deallocates all the nodes except first node, 
   hence , probably you can add the following in the delete_commands.

```
void delete_commands(Command_list **root)
{
    Command_list *temp;
    Command_list *FirstNode= NULL;
    FistNode  = *root;
    while( *root != NULL ){
        temp = (*root)->child;
        //printf("STRING: %s\n", *root->command );
        unallocate( *root );
        *root = temp;

    }
    if ( *FirstNode != NULL ) unallocate(*FirstNode); 
}
```